# Use btguard for anonymous browsing under windows 7 (x64)

Tags: socks-proxy

For those who don't know how it works: btguard is a password protected SOCKS5 proxy. I am looking for an easy way to use it as an internet browsing privacy solution. Here are two options I entertained and found none of them working the way I like:

- There's a couple socksifyer tools, which would start a program and force it to use socks proxy for all network communication. **problems**: 1) couldn't find any that works under windows 7 in x64 mode 2) those which start in x86 mode will not socksify internet explorer anyway
- There's a way to configure browser to use SOCKS, but I couldn't find a way to configure browser to use password protectes SOCKS proxy.
- It's possible to chain local proxy to the one provided by btguard, but I couldn't find any software which will do that. Can someone who succeeded post here a name of software and how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Opera browser supports SOCKS5 with authentication. I've specifically installed it to make more use of btguard for that purpose. Configure the SOCKS5 details via Opera | Settings | Preferences | Advanced | Network | Proxies. 
onfirm all an then type at URL prompt the "opera:config" to access the Preferences Editor. This will allow you to set under the Proxy menu the SOCKS username/password as provided by btguard.

Works great, also while uTorrent already has concurrent connections open.

I couldn't find a way wit Firefox, Chrome and IE yet.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do it under windows, but you can do it under Linux: http://www.squidoo.com/btguard-with-web-browser-in-linux

Comment: Cannot browse to this URL, here's where it lands: http://vvcap.net/db/qAJdqY9clb0HPpP4XdPO.htp